# Confusion about conformality of Möbius maps

Tags: conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I am aware that Möbius maps are conformal maps, that is, they preserve  oriented angles. So I was thinking, say I have a circle in $C$. Then I can find a Möbius map that maps it to a a line (a circle through infinity). Clearly the angle between any two points on the line is the same, however, this is not true for the circle. But Möbius maps are conformal so this must be the case. This seems contradictory. Could someone elaborate on the conformity of Möbius maps that send circles to lines and vice versa?

Comment: "The angle between any two points"? What does that mean?

Comment: As in evaluating the tangents of the curve at these points and setting the angle to be the angle between these tangents.

Comment: you can only measure an angle when you have two curves intersecting at some point. Since you are only talking about one curve there is no angle to be found anywhere. If you want to add lines to the picture then you need to also add their images (or inverse images) by the Mobius transform.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you post this as a answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: The asker meant probably the comparison between non zero angle $\angle ABC$ formed by 3 points on the initial circle and zero angle  $\angle A'B'C'$ formed by their 3 images on the straight line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only measure an angle when you have two curves intersecting at some point. Since you are only talking about one curve there is no angle to be found anywhere. If you want to add lines to one of the pictures then you need to also add their images (or inverse images) by the Mobius transform to the other.